# I am having trouble with daily averages with mutliple date entries

Tags: excel-formula

I have a list of, among other things, dates and hours worked on during each session. This means that I can have multiple entries for the same date. 
Ex:

- |Date|   --  |Hours/session|
- 1/1/2015   -- 1.5
- 1/1/2015  --  2
- 1/1/2015   --  0.5
- 1/3/2015 --   1.5
- 1/3/2015  --   1
- 1/4/2015 --    2
- 1/7/2015 --    1.5

I want to be able to find out how many hours per day I am averaging, but dividing hours by the number of days includes the 2nd, 5th and 6th in the average. In this example, if I take all the hours and divide it by number of days from the beggining to end, I end up with

> (1.5+2+.5+1.5+1+2+1.5=10) 10/7(1st to the 7th)=1.43

instead of the correct daily average of

> 10/4(actual days worked)=2.5

The main problem is that I have a list of over 2k entries, so I cannot go through and do this manually. Help?

Comment: I think what you want is a pivot table: http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

Comment: I think I pretty much just need to to able to count the number of days worked. (in the example it would be 4) out of the array. I don't understand how a pivot table would help with that.

Answer (score 1):

A pivot table could simply give you the result you want.

1. mark your whole table
2. select Insert -> Pivot Table.
3. Click "OK". An empty pivot will be created.
4. In the pivot screen, drag field "date" to the "rows" area.
5. Similarily, drag "Hours/Session" to the "Values" area. And be sure you see select "Sum" there (not "count")

In case you have problems with this, let us know or post a screenshot!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To count number of days:

> =SUMPRODUCT((A2:A8)<>"")/(COUNTIF((A2:A8);(A2:A8))+((A2:A8)="")))

And since I am using indirect referencing here is the actual formula that I used:

> =SUMPRODUCT(((INDIRECT("A" &B2):INDIRECT("A" &B3))<>"")/(COUNTIF((INDIRECT("A" &B2):INDIRECT("A" &B3));(INDIRECT("A" &B2):INDIRECT("A" &B3)))+((INDIRECT("A" &B2):INDIRECT("A" &B3))="")))